# Docker контейнер с ELK после запуска сразу останавливается

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

На сервере стоит portainer.io, я туда установил контейнер с ELK https://hub.docker.com/r/sebp/elk/ , но он после запуска останавливает секунд через 10. В логах есть что-то оп поводу нехватки виртуальной памяти, я расширил её, как и рекомендуется. НО ничего не изменилось. Буду рад любым советам!

> {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,438Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [mapper-extras]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,438Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [parent-join]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,439Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [percolator]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,439Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [rank-eval]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,439Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [reindex]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,439Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [repository-url]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,439Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [search-business-rules]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,439Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [spatial]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,440Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [transport-netty4]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,440Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [vectors]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,440Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-analytics]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,440Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-ccr]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,440Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-core]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,440Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,441Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-graph]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,441Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-ilm]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,441Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-logstash]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,441Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-ml]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,441Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,441Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-rollup]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,442Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-security]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,442Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-sql]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,442Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-voting-only-node]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,442Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-watcher]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:42,443Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "no plugins loaded" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:49,325Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "parsed [0] roles from file [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/roles.yml]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:51,340Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "[controller/102] [Main.cc@110] controller (64 bit): Version 7.4.2 (Build 473f61b8a5238b) Copyright (c) 2019 Elasticsearch BV" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:51,790Z", "level": "DEBUG", "component": "o.e.a.ActionModule", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "Using REST wrapper from plugin org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.Security" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:52,180Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.d.DiscoveryModule", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:53,436Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "initialized" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:53,437Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "starting ..." }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:53,551Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.t.TransportService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "publish_address {172.17.0.44:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:53,559Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.b.BootstrapChecks", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks" }

ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed

[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]

[2]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:53,567Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "stopping ..." }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:53,609Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "stopped" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:53,609Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "closing ..." }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:53,624Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "closed" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:26:53,628Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.m.p.NativeController", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started" }

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:24,192Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.e.NodeEnvironment", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (rootfs)]], net usable_space [14.8gb], net total_space [55.1gb], types [rootfs]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:24,197Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.e.NodeEnvironment", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "heap size [990.7mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:24,200Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "node name [7d9691848473], node ID [JoUV_OkuSsONorjPfReB-A], cluster name [docker-cluster]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:24,200Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "version[7.4.2], pid[1], build[default/docker/2f90bbf7b93631e52bafb59b3b049cb44ec25e96/2019-10-28T20:40:44.881551Z], OS[Linux/3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64/amd64], JVM[AdoptOpenJDK/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/13.0.1/13.0.1+9]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:24,201Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "JVM home [/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:24,201Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-10857677967325486702, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Dio.netty.allocator.type=unpooled, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=536870912, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=docker, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,729Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,729Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [analysis-common]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,730Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [data-frame]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,730Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [flattened]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,730Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [frozen-indices]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,767Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [ingest-common]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,767Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [ingest-geoip]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,768Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [ingest-user-agent]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,768Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [lang-expression]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,768Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [lang-mustache]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,768Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [lang-painless]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,769Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [mapper-extras]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,769Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [parent-join]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,769Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [percolator]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,769Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [rank-eval]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,769Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [reindex]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,770Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [repository-url]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,770Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [search-business-rules]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,770Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [spatial]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,770Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [transport-netty4]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,771Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [vectors]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,771Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-analytics]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,771Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-ccr]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,771Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-core]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,771Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,771Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-graph]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,771Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-ilm]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,772Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-logstash]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,772Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-ml]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,773Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,774Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-rollup]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,774Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-security]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,774Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-sql]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,774Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-voting-only-node]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,774Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-watcher]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:26,775Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "no plugins loaded" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:33,941Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "parsed [0] roles from file [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/roles.yml]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:34,537Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "[controller/115] [Main.cc@110] controller (64 bit): Version 7.4.2 (Build 473f61b8a5238b) Copyright (c) 2019 Elasticsearch BV" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:35,764Z", "level": "DEBUG", "component": "o.e.a.ActionModule", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "Using REST wrapper from plugin org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.Security" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:36,419Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.d.DiscoveryModule", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings]" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:38,000Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "initialized" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:38,000Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "starting ..." }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:38,145Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.t.TransportService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "publish_address {172.17.0.44:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:38,158Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.b.BootstrapChecks", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks" }

ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed

[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]

[2]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:38,166Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "stopping ..." }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:38,250Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "stopped" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:38,250Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "closing ..." }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:38,266Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "closed" }

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-30T13:31:38,268Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.m.p.NativeController", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "7d9691848473", "message": "Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started" }

Comment: Не плохо бы приложить лог, для того, чтобы вам помогли.

Comment: Спасибо, добавил.

Comment: была подобная проблема - на хосте не стартовал контейнер с дженкинсом, на самой виртуалке не хватало ОП, увеличил в 2 раза и помогло. Контейнер запустился.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо увеличить количество виртуальной памяти 
`sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` или добавить параметр в конфигурационный файл
`echo 'vm.max_map_count=262144' >> /etc/sysctl.conf`
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html

Comment: В дальнейшем могут понадобиться дополнительные настройки https://netpoint-dc.com/blog/elasticsearch-cluster-linux/

Comment: Как я и написал, я её расширил, запись sysctl добавилась, но ничего не изменилось.. Есть ещё варианты?

Comment: Попробуйте перезапустить докер, параметры должны подцепиться с хостовой машины 
```#cat /etc/sysctl.conf  | grep -v "^#"
vm.max_map_count=262144``` 

docker exec c244c8649cc2  sysctl -a | grep max_map_count
еще вариант передать через **--sysctl** [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#configure-namespaced-kernel-parameters-sysctls-at-runtime)

Comment: Перезапускал. На Вашу команду отвечает:
grep: cat: /etc/sysctl.conf: No such file or directory
vm.max_map_count=262144: No such file or directory
Файл действительно отсутствует.. И у меня менее 10 секунд для работы с контейнером, потом он падает.

Comment: echo "vm.max_map_count=262200" > cat /etc/sysctl.conf   -  результатов не дает никаких почему-то, будто и не вводил команду

Comment: С официальными image такая же проблема?

Comment: cat в середине команды лишний. На хостовой машине где запускаете контейнер параметр изменился?

Comment: я официальный ставил. на хосте пишет так:
/etc$ cat /etc/sysctl.conf
# sysctl settings are defined through files in
# /usr/lib/sysctl.d/, /run/sysctl.d/, and /etc/sysctl.d/.
#
# Vendors settings live in /usr/lib/sysctl.d/.
# To override a whole file, create a new file with the same in
# /etc/sysctl.d/ and put new settings there. To override
# only specific settings, add a file with a lexically later
# name in /etc/sysctl.d/ and put new settings there.
#
# For more information, see sysctl.conf(5) and sysctl.d(5).

Comment: Запустил контейнер, быстро ввел команду без cat в центре, файл с нужной записью создался, но контейнер все равно падает с той же ошибкой